# How to use EXISTS in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get all the records showing only ID's which didn't go through stutus=2 but have been canceled from specific statuses. Tables are A_ORDERS_LOG and A_ORDERS.

So, each ID can go through various statuses. I am interested to see only those ID's which have been canceled from certain statuses and haven't been through status=2.

I have tried this

```
SELECT *
  FROM A_ORDERS_LOG
 WHERE ( STATUS1 = 0  AND STATUS2  = 11 )
    OR ( STATUS1 = 1  AND STATUS2  = 11 )
    OR ( STATUS1 = 3  AND STATUS2  = 11 )
    OR ( STATUS1 = 4  AND STATUS2  = 11 )
    OR ( STATUS1 = 41 AND STATUS2  = 11 )
    OR ( STATUS1 = 42 AND STATUS2  = 11 )
    OR ( STATUS1 = 43 AND STATUS2  = 11 )
    OR ( STATUS1 = 5  AND STATUS2  = 11 )
    OR ( STATUS1 = 6  AND STATUS2  = 11 )
   AND EXISTS (
       SELECT STATUS1,
              STATUS2
         FROM A_ORDERS_LOG
        WHERE ( STATUS1 != 2 OR STATUS2 != 2 )
          AND ID IN (
              SELECT ID
                FROM A_ORDERS
       )
)
);
```

Status2=11 - means canceling and status1 is the status from which it was canceled.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: its tough to understand your logic with sample data

Answer (score 1):

Seems you need one `exists` and one `not exists` while tiding up the filtering statuses just after the `where` clause :

```
select *
  from a_orders_log o
 where status1 in ( 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 41, 42, 43 ) and status2 = 11 
   and not exists (select 0
                     from a_orders_log o3
                    where 2 in ( status1 , status2 ) 
                      and exists ( select 1 from a_orders o2 where o2.id = o3.id ) );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I am not sure if I underestand this part        
          `where 2 in ( status1 , status2 )`

Comment: you're welcome @IVA. You even can prefer using `where status1=2 and status1=2` instead. Those are identical. I preferred for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding more simplicity by using join instead of exists.

```
select *
  from a_orders_log o
 where status1 in ( 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 41, 42, 43 ) and status2 = 11 
   and not exists (select 0
                     from a_orders_log aoo join a_orders ao on (ao.id=aoo.id)
                    where 2 in ( status1 , status2 ) )
```

@barbaros, It will be appreciated if you can please check it for correctness.

Cheers!!

Comment: yes,you're right it refers to Inner table column (and I took in parentheses as you did ). When I answered, the format of the query was really in mess :)